# How to convert a .doc file to a .pdf without tracking changes, using writer from command line? using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ms-word, libreoffice

I am using either Libre office or MS office to convert docx file to pdf. I am using this php code (for command line code execution)

```
if ($UseLibre)
      $command = 'C:\Progra~2\LibreO~1\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export '.$doc_file_path.' -outdir '.$pdf_file_path; // When using Libre 
else
      $command = 'cscript /nologo D:\wamp\www\doc2pdf.vbs /nologo '.$doc_file_path.' '.$pdf_file_path;  //Whe using MS Office
```

This is working fine. But the problem is that if the docx contain track changes review markup then it affects the alignment in generated pdf.

How can i remove the track changes before generate pdf 
Or is there any parameters extra need to pass to say the libre/ms office to ignore track changes while converting docx?

Comment: If you want to use OpenOffice then you may use from the command line unoconv with latest LibreOffice. https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how to hide/remove the review tracking  changes in the docx document before converting to pdf.
Now am using this code
C:\Progra~2\LibreO~1\program\soffice.exe --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export <docx path> -outdir <pdf_path>